# Matching participants to activities over many rounds

Tags: algorithms

I have a group of N participants, and I need to assign them to M activities. Each activity has a different capacity, from 1 to N.

Each participant ranks the activities in order of preference, and no two activities can share the same ranking.

This happens for many days, and the goal is to:

- ensure that no participant is in the long run, worse off than most other participants
- ensure that if a participant ranks an activity with excess capacity as first, they are always assigned that activity
- ideally, assign no one to their last choice

So for example, Alice can always get her first choice even if Bob only gets his first choice half the time, but only if Alice never picks oversubscribed activities.

I'm sure this is an existing problem, but I'm struggling to find out what it's called. Does anyone know? Or if it's not an existing problem, any thoughts as to a good algorithm for solving it?

Comment: Are you asking us to look for an algorithm that meets a specific requirement or that maximizes a specific objective function?  Or are you asking us to formulate those requirements/objective function for you?  To make the algorithmic task well-defined, you need to precisely specify (a) a set of hard constraints that absolutely must not be violated, and/or (b) a *single* objective function to maximize (this assigns a value to each candidate solution, where the goal is to find the solution whose value is maximized).  It's not clear what those are from your question.

Comment: For instance, you list "goals", but it's not clear if those are hard constraints or just soft goals that you hope can be achieved but are OK to violate if it helps achieve some other goal; it's not clear how you want to trade off between them if they can't all be simultaneously satisfied; and it's not clear what exactly the first one means (you need to be more precise about "long run" and "most").  Also, can you define what "excess capacity" means?  Also, take a look at the assignment problem and the stable marriage problem and see if this helps you formulate your problem.